# horizontal center css circle in bootstrap column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

We try to center a CSS circle with a image and a label overlaying the circle. The circle should be horizontally centered in a bootstrap column. Goal is to have this circle always in the horizontal center. Any advise is welcome.

Please see following [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/metaxos/b11nba98/1/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="circle1Wrapper">
            <div class="circle-textSmall bubble1outer">
                <div> <span class="bubbleIconSmall">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40/" />
                    </span><span class="bubbleHeadSmall">label</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle1Wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.bubble1outer {
    position: absolute;
}
.circle-textSmall div {
    width: 125px;
}
.circle-textSmall div {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    padding-top: 15%;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
}
span.bubbleIconSmall > img {
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
}
.circle-textSmall:after {
    width: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 125px;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
.circle-textSmall:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 250px;
    background: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

It should look like this: [image]

Comment: could you add a screenshot with the desired effect?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/7qo4grfp/ ?

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Yes almost. The circle background color should be grey and the image is on line over the LABEL within the cirlce. I took you jsfiddle and i just miss the label (seems to be behind the image). http://jsfiddle.net/metaxos/7qo4grfp/1/

Comment: See the new [JSFiddle][1]. Now the label and the image are in each in one <div> within a "wrapper" div. If you see any simpler solution please give feedback.

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/metaxos/7qo4grfp/4/

Comment: What do you mean by "on line over the label"? Do you want to be picture and text side by side (in the same line), or the image behind the text, or the image right above the text?

Comment: @alvaro-montoro Now it is done like i need it: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/metaxos/7qo4grfp/4/).

Comment: @user3008011 visualisation was added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@metaxos, I wanted to put this as a comment, but it is a bit long.

Even when you found a solution that works for you, I think that you may want to consider cleaning that code a bit; look how the original example got rid of most of the code and just kept one `div`:

- `.innerwrapper` is unnecessary (why not put that style directly on `#myCircleDiv`?);
- Same thing for the div that holds the image (you could put that style directly on the image!);
- And the `img` itself can go too (and use it as background of `#myCircleDiv`).

This is my opinion (feel free to ignore it), but I think you should aim for something cleaner and easier to maintain, rather than a more complex and elaborated (but unnecessary) structure (unless it is required by the user/customer). The simpler, the better.

In that sense, this ([you can see it working on this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qo4grfp/5/)):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="myCircleDiv">LABEL</div>

/* CSS */
#myCircleDiv {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:375px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/") #ccc no-repeat 50% 38px;
}
```

Looks beter than this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="myCircleDiv">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
        <div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" />
        </div>
        <div>LABEL</div>
    </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
#myCircleDiv {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ccc;
    background-size:250px 250px;
    line-height:250px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.innerWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
.innerWrapper div {
    float: left;
    height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 125px;
}

.innerWrapper div img {
    margin-top: 38px;
}
```

And the result is exaclty the same. But again... that's my opinion :)